# Why can't Eli undo what he did near the end of Seizure (SGU Season 2 Episode 15)?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

In Stargate Universe, Season 2 Episode 15 (Seizure), there is something Eli does near the end that seems reversible.

> At the end of the episode, Eli has to move Ginn and Amanda into a quarantine, to bring Rush back after Rush has been uploaded into the ship. Is there a reason that after Rush is back, he can't just bring them back from quarantine? Or, was there something a bit more permanent about the whole thing that I just missed?

Comment: For the people who'll be reading this question after a few weeks have passed, please include a precise reference to the episode.

Comment: @Gilles: The name is Seizure, but I'll put in the season/ show number information as well.

Comment: I had the impression they couldn't be trusted, seeing as to how they had already endangered the ship and its crew for their own narrow purposes. But, I suspect its weakly supported by evidence and put there primarily because it creates conflict, i.e. a cost to Eli and Rush for the quarantine.

Comment: If you are answering the question, please post as an answer and not a comment

Comment: It's not really adequately explained, as far as I'm concerned. Their predicament doesn't really many any logical sense, but the writers wanted to force Eli to 'sacrifice' them while keeping the characters in the background for possible future storylines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was nothing in the episode that explains why Eli couldn't reverse the procedure. The mostly like reason is as Asmor suggested in the comments to your question; "the writers wanted to force Eli to 'sacrifice' them while keeping the characters in the background for possible future storylines."

> Additionally there wasn't any explanation of how the quarantine was supposed to work. Remember he was cutting Rush off from Amanda by moving 2 sentient computer programs that simulate Amanda & Ginn but which have also somehow become meshed together. Presumably they had to be moved to a non-networked computer on Destiny. However given the apparent speed at which they were moved to quarantine, it seems unlikely that they were transferred via non-networked methods (e.g. copied to an external hard drive).

Comment: I'd argue the opposite based on reallife technology - copying to/from USB hard drives is faster than over a network, which makes your suggestion even more plausible.

Comment: Consider a real-life topic: [Antimalware Software](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64443/can-malware-be-dangerous-even-when-quarantined)

Answer (score 2):

Eli could not undo what Amanda had done to the system (in creating the world that Rush became stuck in) which is why he had to move her and Ginn to quarantine (where one goes it seems the other must go, from what I can remember that's why Ginn had to be put in quarantine too) so if Eli were to take them out of quarantine the program would still be active and wreak havoc on Rush's mind, as the battle simulation's Destiny ran effected Colonel Young.